# How to separate two words in hangman game?

Tags: vb.net

I have seen a lot of hangman game related questions, including same question as mine **but** not for VB.NET, rather some other programming language. I have code for generating dashes (the _) but have no idea how to separate two words (remove single dash between words).

This is the code I use for generating dashes in a word. I hope there is a way to make generator code detect spaces and separate words without doing something completely different.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim SecretWord As String
    Dim WordLength As Integer
    Dim WordCount As Integer
    Dim Guesses As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = Nothing
        SecretWord = TextBox1.Text
        WordLength = SecretWord.Length - 1
        For position As Integer = 0 To WordLength
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " _ "
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I didn't try anything yet, mostly because I am not best with VB.NET. Sorry for my poor English and grammar.

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: *I didn't try anything yet* - then how will you succeed?

Comment: it's not really a homework, rather something that i was wanting to make myself

Comment: ````Dim SecretWord As String() = TextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(New Char() {"_"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)````  Then you can loop through each SecretWord in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what character is at a certain position in a string, you can treat the string like an array, with an indexer:

```
Dim str = "Hello world"
Dim letter = str(1) 'letter e
```

Indexing runs from 0

So as you're looping you could be pulling the character out and looking at it instead of always making a `_`

```
    For position As Integer = 0 To WordLength
        If SecretWord(position) <> " "c Then 'if the char at this position is not a space
          Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " _ "
        Else
          'what do you want to put in if it IS a space?
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I will try using this!

Comment: @LilProgrammer The way to thank people on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers and earn you a couple of points. You would know this if you had taken the [tour].